# cannot create temporary table from select union in a read only database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a temporary table in a read only replica MYSQL 5.6.44 database:

```
create temporary table tmp_username
select username from sync_event where date(last_modified) = '2020-06-15' 
union
select username from sync_outcome where date(last_modified) = '2020-06-15';
```

I get the error:

```
The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
```

However, without the union it works ok:

```
create temporary table tmp_username
select username from sync_event where date(last_modified) = '2020-06-15'
```

Is this a known limitation of MySql or am I doing something wrong? I can't find any reference to it in the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a bug to me - https://bugs.mysql.com/
simpler case to test: `create temporary table tbl select 1 from dual union select 2 from dual`

Comment: OT comment. If `last_modified` is a date, it doesn't need to be wrapped in `date()`

Comment: maybe wrap the union select in an inner select like `CREATE TABLE name AS SELECT * FROM (select ... union... select)`

Comment: thanks @danblack, I'll report as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For avoid the limit 
You could try using a subquery

```
    create temporary table tmp_username
    select *
    from (

        select username from sync_event where date(last_modified) = '2020-06-15' 
        union
        select username from sync_outcome where date(last_modified) = '2020-06-15'
    ) t;
```